# Метод прогонки в scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

Коллеги, доброе время суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализован ли метод прогонки для решения СЛАУ с 3-х диагональной матрицей в библиотеке scipy в "чистом" виде? Почитал про функцию solve_banded: там LU-факторизация используется, что сказывается на времени исполнения, например:

```
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter

# для метода прогонки. 1 над диагональю. И 1 под диагональю
u = 1
l = 1
n = 5
m = 5
a = [[2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 2, 3]]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
ab = np.zeros((u + l + 1, m))

for j in range(m):
    for i in range(n):
        index = u + i - j
        if 0 <= index < u + l + 1:
            ab[index][j] = a[i][j]
t1=perf_counter()            
ans = linalg.solve_banded((l, u), ab, b)
print(' solve_banded time=',perf_counter()-t1)
print(ab)
print(' ans=',ans)

def TDMAsolver (a, b, c, d):
    '''
    TDMA solver, a b c d can be NumPy array type or Python list type.
    refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm
    '''
    nf = len(a)     # number of equations
    ac, bc, cc, dc = map(np.array, (a, b, c, d))     # copy the array
    for it in range(1, nf):
        mc = ac[it]/bc[it-1]
        bc[it] = bc[it] - mc*cc[it-1]
        dc[it] = dc[it] - mc*dc[it-1]
    xc = ac
    xc[-1] = dc[-1]/bc[-1]
    for il in range(nf-2, -1, -1):
        xc[il] = (dc[il]-cc[il]*xc[il+1])/bc[il]
    del bc, cc, dc  # delete variables from memory
    return xc

x = [0] * n
aa=np.array([0,1,1,1,2])
bb=np.array([2,2,2,2,3])
cc=np.array([1,1,1,1,0])
t1=perf_counter()
x=TDMAsolver (aa, bb, cc, b)
print(' progon time=',perf_counter()-t1)
print(' x=',x)

**********
Результаты:
 solve_banded time= 0.00013119999994160025
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 3.]
 [1. 1. 1. 2. 0.]]
 ans= [0.14285714 0.71428571 0.42857143 1.42857143 0.71428571]
 progon time= 6.579999990208307e-05
 x= [0 0 1 1 1]
```

т.е. самописная прогонка считает в 2 раза быстрее...

Comment: P.S. Извиняюсь, только что заметил, что результаты solve_banded дает другие. Ищу неточность...

Comment: Смотрели эту функцию - [solveh_banded](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html#scipy.linalg.solveh_banded)? Вроде, подходит для вашего случая (положительно-определённой матрицы).
Также функция [solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html#scipy.linalg.solve) имеет параметр `assume_a`, через который задаётся предположение о виде матрицы (есть учёт симметричности).